# setup mail in virtual dedicated server in godaddy

Tags: windows-server-2008, email, virtualization, dedicated-server

I bought virtual dedicated server in godaddy. client having domain name in networksolutions. i changed  the A record to denote godaddy server. how can i setup mail.there is no mail information such as username,passsword not provided with godaddy vps.

Comment: Did you purchase a control panel for the server or are you managing everything via RDC?

Answer (score 1):

You've purchased a virtual server image.  You now need to install the mail software you want, create the relevant users, and do all the configuration yourself.